# The book saids so, but the importing gave a traceback?

Tags: python, traceback

The importing is as below:

```
from settings import Settings
```

And it gave a traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\0Data\Desktop\Alien_invasion\Aliens.py", line 5, in <module>
    from settings import Settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

I checked. It's the exact same. The book is Python crash course 2nd edition page 235.

Answer (score 1):

There's a file you're missing that you need, from a quick Google search:

https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc

Pull it from there ^ depends on what chapter you're on. Make sure you put it in your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

[The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/index.html) does not have any module named `settings`. Most likely is a module created previously in the book or something installed with Pip